# Pagination in JSP using DataTables

Tags: java, jsp, web, datatables

I am planning to implement pagination in my JSP using DataTables. I previously implemented it using DisplayTag Library but looks like it is getting old now. I couldn't find a good example or a resource about Datatables on how to do it in a JSP. I have a list of object in my JSP and intended to show 10 records per page. With DisplayTag I did it very easily but with DataTables I am not exactly sure if it is straight forward and the changes would just be in the JSP. I want some thoughts or if there is any other library out there to help accomplish my goal.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go with this link.
[DatabaleExample](http://www.opencodez.com/java/datatable-with-spring-boot.htm)

Comment: Thanks Kuldeep. This once is really nice to start with.